# vuejs ref property has no effect when using with createElement

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've written a custom render function for a Vue Component, but when I set the "ref" property in the data object that is passed to the createElement function, nothing shows up in the $refs of the root vm (VueComponent)

```
Vue.component('sm-form-row', {
        render: function (createElement) {
            // Create the Row Div and append the columns
            return createElement('div', {
                    class: {
                        'row': true
                    },
                    ref: 'some computed value'
                });
        }
});
```

What am I missing, the class is being applied correctly but the $refs keep showing empty.

Comment: How and where (lifecycle hook) are you accessing that the `$ref` object?

Comment: Ok. Found the problem. I was looking at the $refs at the root level component. It's actually creating the refs under the parent component of where this component is defined.

Comment: You can still access the reference in the same component you created it, the trick is in the lifecycle you're getting it. You can always create a computed property that checks for that element to be created

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` is beign applied and i made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/658tdhx4/) to see it that it works.

But,if you want to add a reference to `sm-form-row` component then you have to add the `ref` attribute in the parent component.For example in parent component:

```
<sm-form-row ref="formRow" />
```

And in your parent component you can access it as:

```
this.$refs.formRow
```

Also you will be able to access the methods of the child component.For example if the child component has a method called myMethod you can access it in parent component like this:

```
this.$refs.formRow.myMethod
```

Comment: I want to create refs for dynamically created elements.

Comment: Yes,the ref is being created

Comment: So you want to set the ref dynamically?It is simple.I updated my fiddle and set the ref with dynamic value passed from parent component.Take e look